# Convert weird characters into readable text

Tags: javascript

Using this function

```
function decode (data) {
  return (new Buffer('' + data, 'base64')).toString()
}
```

this line in javascript is supposed to return some human readable text like so

```
var text = decode(fs.readFile(path.join(inbox.dir, inbox.messages[found].hash), 'utf8'))
```

but instead returns this characters when I log text in the console

```
�w^~)�
```

I also tried to console log without the decode but it returns undefined, hope someone can help me with the a proper deconversion script

Comment: What's the input format? What are the byte contents of that file?

Comment: Well I think you shouldn't take an UTF-8 string and claim that it's `base64` data? Have you tried just dropping that "decode" call - what's the result?

Comment: console logging without the decode returns "undefined" the data comes from a json file

Comment: Oh right, of course, that makes sense - `readFile` is an asynchronous function. It does not return anything, it takes a callback instead!

Comment: removing the 'utf8' still returns the same characters

Comment: That's not what I said. Have you read [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), specifically the example on how to use `fs.readFile`?

Comment: got it, i was just adding additional info from my debugging